# How to subtract two dates in Laravel5.4

Tags: laravel, date, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, php-carbon

I'm projects table that users projects is saved in it and have start_time and finish_time and price,I give it as form that has this code:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <input type="date" class="form-control" name="start_time" >
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
 <input type="date" class="form-control" name="finish_time" >
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price" >
 </div>
```

Now,I Want subtract dates and if result be Negative Can multiply price and result,How I can do this?

Comment: Use Carbon  Class

Comment: please write as code for me

Comment: **Stack Overflow is not a Free Coding Platform**. Here is the documentation http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ ... try it yourself! If you have something that you believe should work but do not, post it here and we are glade to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you should do is something like this:

```
$start_time = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->input('start_time'));
$finish_time = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->input('finish_time'));

$price = $request->input('price');

$result = $start_time->diffInDays($finish_time, false);

if ($result < 0) {
  $price = $price * $result;
}
```

I don't know which dates you wanted to subtract so make sure that you valid one. You should use either:

```
$result = $start_time->diffInDays($finish_time, false);
```

or

```
$result = $finish_time->diffInDays($start_time, false);
```

Keep in mind you need to pass `false` as 2nd argument to `diffInDays` method  - otherwise you will always get positive result.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller method you can calculate the difference:

```
   $start_time = $request->input('start_time');
   $start_time_ob = new \Carbon\Carbon($start_time);
```

Or you can use the static Carbon::parse() method:

```
$finish_time = $request->input('finish_time');
$finish_time_ob = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($date);
```

For your purposes you can use the this full example:

```
$diff =  $finish_time_ob->diffInDays($start_time_ob);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Expiry Date**

```
$expirydate = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($object->end_date);
```

> $expirydate = 2020-06-09 00:00:00

**Returns Current Date**

```
$today = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
```

> $today = 2019-09-05 13:53:47

**Total number of day days remaining to expire**

```
$difference = $today->diffInDays($expirydate, false)
```

> **$difference = 277**

Total 277 days remaining to expire.

> If Days are coming in negative number it means it has been expired otherwise
>   yet to expire.